# Adding parameters to custom provider in puppet

Tags: puppet

I've forked one of the existing package providers (appdmg.rb) to use in my module. I simply want to ask an extra parameter "path" as a custom installation target path. I use @resource[:path] in the modified module and I've put it in /lib subdirectory. After restarting puppet master, it is recognised and synchronised to agent properly - I've checked it's availability in /var/lib/puppet/ on the agent, but I get a parameter error during test run:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter path at /etc/puppet/modules/xcode/manifests/init.pp:6 on node lon02-mac-09.local
```

The manifest code is:

```
package {
  "xcode-${version}" :
    provider => 'appdmg2',
    source   => "/storage/xcode-${version}.dmg",
    path     => "/Applications/Xcode${version}.app",
}
```

Is there anything special I have to do to make it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite that simple. The `provider` serves as the backend for a `type`. To enable Puppet to use an additional parameter to the `package` type, you will have to add it to the respective type code such as the `source` param in the [upstream code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/package.rb#L307-316).

Once you patch that in, `@resource[:path]` should indeed work inside the provider instances.

Of course, such additions are not suitable for a module, so you would techically need to actually add a new type of your own (and sadly, there is no subtyping yet).

It may be worth checking wether [install_options](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package-attribute-install_options) can perhaps solve your problem using the existing provider.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately install_options are not really helpful in case of dmg images, however looking at the code you supplied and at other providers, it seems I could possibly reuse this attribute for my purposes by parsing it in the provider code.

Comment: Oh, that's a neat (albeit slightly evil) idea. +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add a new parameter thus:

```
Puppet::Type.type(:package).newparam(:path) do
    desc "Specify alternative package-path"
end
```

The above snippet lives in `modules/YOURMODULE/lib/puppet/provider/package/YOURPROVIDER.rb` -- in the same file, where the actual provider-implementation itself resides.

Unfortunately, I still can't figure out, how to actually access the value of this parameter specified in the Puppet-manifest from inside my new package-provider...